# What are some names for a Wizard/Witch's work-room?

Tags: magic

A scientist has a laboratory - what does a wizard/witch have?

This would be the place they keep ingredients, books, cauldrons and magic mirrors.

In my case, this room is in a castle, and the king might come to visit it.

Ex: Magicarium, Spellatorium. Hopefully better examples exist? Examples from fiction are welcome also.

Comment: This would be better answered in some other stack-exchange, like the writing stack exchange OR possibly mythology

Comment: I'm afraid that people here believe any and all questions about names are not part of worldbuilding, so your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I'm not voting to close, but KeizerHarm is right, it's a legitimate concern.

Comment: VTC opinion-based. [worldbuilding.se] has consistently closed "what is the best name" questions because there is [no objective answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609). At best, the answers violate the [help/dont-ask]'s rules about not asking questions where no answer is any better than another. At worst, you're just asking us for a list of synonyms, which is what dictionaries and Google are for.

Comment: For a person who is not a mage, such a room is called a [study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Study_(room)) or a [cabinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_(room)). Since in real life there are no sorceres, there is no real life word for such a room specifically as used by warlocks. For reference, there is an [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange. (And -1 for the horrendous barbarism \*\**spellatorium*.) (BTW, a \*\**magicarium* is presumably the place where one magicates.)

Comment: "lair" or "latibulum"

Comment: Arcanium :) I can't add this as an answer because the question is closed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Home Sweet Home***:

Generally, [witches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witchcraft) are agrarian and common, so they work in a kitchen, at a cauldron and a hearth. They are secretive and will do rituals in the woods, away from their homes. They may have a herbarium and garden. If in house, they will practice in a basement. They rarely have a dedicated place unless it's a hut in the woods away from people. Magical materials will be hidden away. Generally witchcraft comes more from an intrinsic quality than things.

[Wizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_(fantasy)), on the other hand, are more legitimate, and have infrastructure. They will have a library, possibly a tower, a study, a laboratory, workshop, or both, possibly a brewery for potions (alchemy), they may have an observatory or scrying room, a conjuring room (with pentagrams, magic circles, etc.). Often you can cloak a wizard in scientific terminology and it sounds plausible.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest **aerie**.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/aerie

> aerie or aer·y [ air-ee, eer-ee ]
>
> - the nest of a bird of prey, as an eagle or a hawk.
> - a lofty nest of any large bird.
> - a house, fortress, or the like, located high on a hill or mountain: They felt protected from invaders in the hilltop aerie.
> - an apartment or office on a high floor in a high-rise building: a penthouse aerie with a spectacular view.

Using that term for what you want is not common but neither is it unheard of. An aerie would be in a tower and has the connotation of an eagle.  I think of Lovecraft's [The Strange High House in the Mist](https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/shh.aspx) which he describes at one point as an "unknown and terrible eyrie".  That alternate spelling also has connotations of eerie which worked well for that story.

Comment: The connotations of "eyrie" is that it is a dwelling place (for men or raptors) "high up". It has nothing to do with magic.

Comment: @AlexP - true, true.  But y is a great admirer of e and sometimes can be an understudy.